# PostgreSQL: selecting large objects (e.g., text) non programmatically (with a tool)

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

We are using PostgreSQL with JPA which maps large strings to columns with type `TEXT`.

While programmatically we are able to read and write the data, pgAdmin and psql just show me the object ID when I select the data.

Is there a way/tool to quickly select the data without having to use some API (e.g., JDBC)?

An example:

```
doi=> \d+ xmlsnippet;
                           Table "doi.xmlsnippet"
    Column    |          Type          | Modifiers | Storage  | Description 
--------------+------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------
 dbid         | bigint                 | not null  | plain    | 
 version      | bigint                 | not null  | plain    | 
 datasnippet  | text                   |           | extended | 
 doi          | character varying(255) |           | extended | 
 doipool_dbid | bigint                 |           | plain    |
```

The column `datasnippet` contains some large strings (with XML code)

When I select it, I get

```
doi=> select * from xmlsnippet;
 dbid  | version | datasnippet |           doi            | doipool_dbid 
-------+---------+-------------+--------------------------+--------------
    43 |       0 | 282878      | 10.3929/ethz-a-000077127 |           13
    44 |       0 | 282879      | 10.3929/ethz-a-000085677 |           13
    45 |       0 | 282880      | 10.3929/ethz-a-000085786 |           13
    46 |       0 | 282881      | 10.3929/ethz-a-000087642 |           13
    47 |       0 | 282882      | 10.3929/ethz-a-000088898 |           13

                   ^^^^^^^
```

**Edit**: if I perform the same query using JDBC I get the expected content (the text I stored in the column)

Comment: A column of type TEXT is supposed to contain the text itself, not a reference to the contents. In the select * shown above, it is apparent that the datasnippet column is misused to store a reference to the real text that would be stored somewhere else, probably in a different table. If that theory is correct and you locate that table, you'll be able to JOIN it to xmlsnippet and create a view that would output xmlsnippet.* plus the text you're interested in.

Comment: @DanielVérité The problem is that there are no other tables and that if I do a `select datasnippet from xmlsnippet` for example using JDBC I get the data and write the data without any explicit joins.

Comment: @Matteo: you are either not showing us the correct table definition or you are connecting to a different database from within your JDBC application. A text column is not a "large object" and does not contain an "object id" unless you store it in there yourself. Is it possible that JPA is doing some kind of "magic" there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps one of "the usual suspects" (i.e. JPA / Hibernate / PostgreSQL JDBC driver) mapped the column into the "Large Object" system of PostgreSQL.

A quick test in the `psql` shell:

```
db=> \lo_export 282878 /tmp/x.txt
lo_export
```

would export the stuff referenced by the first id from your example into the file `/tmp/x.txt`. Examine it with an editor. Tell us whether that's your data or not.

If this kind of mapping really happened, then you have a maintenance problem - large object must be deleted by hand and have some other intrinsic shortcomings. But that's another story.

Comment: Ok, I get the data. Then I'll try to change the mapping. I was just confused by the fact that the table definition didn't show anything. In fact it is not easy to see if 282878 is the content of a `TEXT` column or the ID of a large object.

Comment: That's one of the strange things happening here. I also would have expected at least a numeric column type (`oid`, `integer`, ...) but __NOT__ `text`.

Comment: Yes I thought the same, hence my question :-)

Answer (score 2):

In pgAdmin III, I use:

```
select dType, id, loread(lo_open(docxml::::int, 131072), 999999999) from XmlPadraoNFe
```

See: [pgAdmin III: How to view a blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14875748/pgadmin-iii-how-to-view-a-blob)