# pgAdmin III: How to view a blob?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I understand that PostgreSQL writes BLOB content to a separate table, but is there any way to view the blob contents in an easy and convenient way from inside pgAdmin?

Comment: What datatype is the "blob" column? `bytea` or `oid`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "easy and convenient" but the best you can do is `lo_read(...)`

This presents the `lob` as a `bytea`.

This is easy and convenient in the sense of getting data out but you pgAdmin won't convert from an escaped string back into the original binary for you so you are left looking at the textual representation of the binary, so it is not "easy and convenient" if you want to show the image contained in a lob when that is in png format or anything.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up using too... I just hoped there was a more convenient way.

For the record, here's what I ended up using:


select dType, id, loread(lo_open(docxml::::int, 131072), 999999999)
from XmlPadraoNFe

Comment: BTW, I found out a few months after posting this question that you can use `lo_get()` to do the same thing: `select dType, id, lo_get(docxml::int) from XmlPadraoNFe`

Answer (score 42):

```
SELECT encode(blobdata::bytea, 'escape') FROM table as o where o.blobdata != ''
```

where

1. blobdata is the bytea column (blob)
2. "table" is the table that contains the column blobdata

Comment: What was the need for `as o where o.blobdata != '`

Comment: @JanacMeena probably `encode` fails on empty values. TIY :)

Answer (score 3):

If we need SQL operations through SQL Clients (like pgAdmin) on binary columns, it would be better to use base64 encoding as below

**To fetch binary data in base64 format**

```
select id, encode(blob_column::bytea, 'base64') as blob_column from blob_table where id=1;
```

**To update binary data by providing base64 formatted data**

```
update blob_table set blob_column = decode('J0u0v1h4CulinCwUvk4dhw==', 'base64') where id=1;
```